# How to know if a string is inside of a another by skips none or some letters ,

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to write a program to check if string is inside of another in any way? I don't mean the contain method. Something like string "AgBgC" contains the string "ABC" or for another one like "browndcodw" contains "brown" and "cow". However, "browndcodw" DO NOT contain "woc", since they are not in order. I first using recursion, but it to slow. I wonder if there is a faster way to do so. And the following is my code:

```
bool dfs(char *arr, char *word, int index, int totalLength){
    if (index >= totalLength) return true;
    for (int i = 0; i<totalLength; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == word[i]) {
            if (dfs(arr, word, index + 1, totalLength)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Please share the attempt you have made. We are not going to simply write a solution for you.

Comment: You should write a program. If you did it and still have the problem, then provide the exact code that you suspect to be wrong.

Comment: I recommend using a loop.  Try writing a simple program that loops through a string, printing one character per line.  Use `std::string` for the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is failry simple. Go through all characters of the input string.

Check, if it does match with the first character of the search string. Increment the index in the search string. Next compare to the second character and so on and so on.

If all characters from search string have been match, then the result is positive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    // Input data
    const std::string inputString{ "browndcodw" };

    // We want to match the characters of this search string
    const std::string searchString{ "cow" };

    // Index in the search string. Will point to the 0th, 1st, 2nd ..... character
    size_t indexInSearchString{};

    // Iterate over all characters from the input string to compare them
    for (const char c : inputString) {

        // If the charcter in the input string is equal to the current search string character
        if (c == searchString[indexInSearchString]) {

            // Then check the next character of the search string
            ++indexInSearchString;
        }
    }

    // If we could match all characters in the search string
    if (indexInSearchString == searchString.size())
        std::cout << "\nResult: '" << searchString << "' is in '" << inputString << "'\n";
    else
        std::cerr << "\nError:'" << searchString << "' is NOT in '" << inputString << "'\n";

    return 0;
}
```